# How to check IMAP folder size in Outlook 2010 or in a standalone tool?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

I think thunderbird is able to achieve this but can I check the size of my IMAP folders in Outlook 2010 or via a small program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Outlook 2007 you can right-click the IMAP folder and choose Properties.  In the General tab of the Properties dialog is a button labeled "folder size" which, if you click it, will tell you the current folder's size, with and without sub-folders included.

In Outlook 2010, right-click the IMAP folder and choose Data File Properties. In the General tab, click the Folder Size button.

Comment: thx, that answers my question. But I made the wrong question as with this I can only see the size of 1 folder at a time, I wanted to check all the folders size to know which one is consuming all my quota :) If anyone knows that, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

On Outlook 2016 it works. Right click on a folder -> Properties -> 'Folder size' button. It will display current folder and all sub folders size.